# why janus will crash abnormally,lit seem to be related to libmicrohttpd

Tags: janus, janus-gateway

Have you encountered this problem?  system:redhat8, janus:0.9.2 version, libmicrohttpd:0.9.69version

```
#0  0x00007f02abb6c37f in raise () at /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f02abb56db5 in abort () at /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f02abbaf4e7 in __libc_message () at /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f02abbb65ec in .annobin_top_check.start () at /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f02abbb97f4 in _int_malloc () at /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007f02abbbb8d6 in calloc () at /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x00007f0272bd415a in internal_add_connection
    (daemon=daemon@entry=0x18fbd70, client_socket=client_socket@entry=23, addr=addr@entry=0x7f02723c84a0, addrlen=28, external_add=external_add@entry=false, non_blck=non_blck@entry=true) at daemon.c:2498
        connection = <optimized out>
        i = <optimized out>
        eno = 0
#7  0x00007f0272bd4ce5 in MHD_accept_connection (daemon=daemon@entry=0x18fbd70) at daemon.c:3317
```

it seems to be related to libmicrohttpd